# How to paraphrase string using NLTK in python

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework, nltk

I'm trying to write an API that returns given number of paraphrased variants of original string which user passes as an argument to the GET request. The string is passed as Parse Tree. Also user should be able to specify the number of lines in the response, but this is optional (default 20 lines).

Original string:

```
The charming Gothic Quarter, or Barri Gòtic, has narrow medieval streets filled with trendy bars, clubs and Catalan restaurants.
```

Example of query:

```
localhost:<port>/paraphrase?tree=(S (NP (NP (DT The) (JJ charming) (NNP Gothic) (NNP
Quarter) ) (, ,) (CC or) (NP (NNP Barri) (NNP Gòtic) ) ) (, ,) (VP (VBZ has) (NP (NP
(JJ narrow) (JJ medieval) (NNS streets) ) (VP (VBN filled) (PP (IN with) (NP (NP (JJ
trendy) (NNS bars) ) (, ,) (NP (NNS clubs) ) (CC and) (NP (JJ Catalan) (NNS
restaurants) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Example of string:

```
(S (NP (NP (DT The) (JJ charming) (NNP Gothic) (NNP
Quarter) ) (, ,) (CC or) (NP (NNP Barri) (NNP Gòtic) ) ) (, ,) (VP (VBZ has) (NP (NP
(JJ narrow) (JJ medieval) (NNS streets) ) (VP (VBN filled) (PP (IN with) (NP (NP (JJ
trendy) (NNS bars) ) (, ,) (NP (NNS clubs) ) (CC and) (NP (JJ Catalan) (NNS
restaurants) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

API should return JSON response with variants of string.

Example:

```
{
    "paraphrases": [
        {
            "tree": "(S (NP (NP (DT The) (JJ charming) (NNP Gothic) (NNP Quarter)) (, ,) (CC or) (NP (NNP Barri) (NNP Gòtic))) (, ,) (VP (VBZ has) (NP (NP (JJ narrow) (JJ medieval) (NNS streets)) (VP (VBN filled) (PP (IN with) (NP (NP (NNS clubs)) (, ,) (NP (JJ trendy) (NNS bars)) (CC and) (NP (JJ Catalan) (NNS restaurants))))))))"
        },
        {
            "tree": "(S (NP (NP (DT The) (JJ charming) (NNP Gothic) (NNP Quarter)) (, ,) (CC or) (NP (NNP Barri) (NNP Gòtic))) (, ,) (VP (VBZ has) (NP (NP (JJ narrow) (JJ medieval) (NNS streets)) (VP (VBN filled) (PP (IN with) (NP (NP (JJ trendy) (NNS bars)) (, ,) (NP (JJ Catalan) (NNS restaurants)) (CC and) (NP (NNS clubs))))))))"
        },
        {
            "tree": "(S (NP (NP (DT The) (JJ charming) (NNP Gothic) (NNP Quarter)) (, ,) (CC or) (NP (NNP Barri) (NNP Gòtic))) (, ,) (VP (VBZ has) (NP (NP (JJ narrow) (JJ medieval) (NNS streets)) (VP (VBN filled) (PP (IN with) (NP (NP (JJ Catalan) (NNS restaurants)) (, ,) (NP (NNS clubs)) (CC and) (NP (JJ trendy) (NNS bars))))))))"
        },
        {
            "tree": "(S (NP (NP (DT The) (JJ charming) (NNP Gothic) (NNP Quarter)) (, ,) (CC or) (NP (NNP Barri) (NNP Gòtic))) (, ,) (VP (VBZ has) (NP (NP (JJ narrow) (JJ medieval) (NNS streets)) (VP (VBN filled) (PP (IN with) (NP (NP (NNS clubs)) (, ,) (NP (JJ Catalan) (NNS restaurants)) (CC and) (NP (JJ trendy) (NNS bars))))))))"
        },
        {
            "tree": "(S (NP (NP (DT The) (JJ charming) (NNP Gothic) (NNP Quarter)) (, ,) (CC or) (NP (NNP Barri) (NNP Gòtic))) (, ,) (VP (VBZ has) (NP (NP (JJ narrow) (JJ medieval) (NNS streets)) (VP (VBN filled) (PP (IN with) (NP (NP (JJ Catalan) (NNS restaurants)) (, ,) (NP (JJ trendy) (NNS bars)) (CC and) (NP (NNS clubs))))))))"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to do this using the transformers library, but it only confused me and I realized that I need to do everything using NLTK.